WheelEvent deltaX/Y and resulting scroll direction
I know this has been asked before but there's no definitive answer on that question.
MDN says:

Even when the wheel event does trigger scrolling, the delta* values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction.

However, the spec says:

If a user agent scrolls as the default action of the wheel event then the sign of the delta SHOULD be given by a right-hand coordinate system where positive X, Y, and Z axes are directed towards the right-most edge, bottom-most edge, and farthest depth (away from the user) of the document, respectively.

And the full-page example in this question that reported the opposite behaviour in Edge seems to now give expected sign of delta* suggesting it indeed was a bug that was fixed in Edge.
Also, on a discussion about this on Bugzilla, a comment by a representative, suggests that the spec is clear and that the sign of delta* should indeed indicate the direction of the resulting (if any) scroll event in the expected way (negative deltaX means left, positive means right; negative deltaY means down, positive means up).
So my questions are:

Why does the MDN page says that the sign of the delta* values doesn't necessarily reflect scrolling direction? Am I misunderstanding what they mean in the sentence above? Is it because the spec says "SHOULD" rather than "MUST"?
As developers, can we safely assume that signs of delta* reflect the direction of the would-be scroll action? gsap seems to assume this...


@Yogi I understand that wheel doesn't necessarily result in a scroll event, however what MDN says is that "delta* values doesn't necessarily reflect scrolling direction" which to me means the direction of scroll that results from wheel, if any. Otherwise if there's no scroll, then of course there's no sense in talking about a scroll direction.

@Yogi Ah very good point! I initially tried this same experiment but didn't think to press and hold Shift as I didn't know it behaves like that. Thank you.

Looks like there's a shiftKey property on the WheelEvent that indicates if it is pressed or not while the event fired and indeed it's true when I hold down Shift. So that can be used to determine the direction together with the delta values perhaps.
